# dereferencing pointer to incomplete type in kernel

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Recently I tried to modify the kernel code of 3.13.11. I added a header file in /include dir. In this file, I try to use the task_struct but encountering the following error:

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  rbuffer_free(&(task->task_pri));
```

My code is as below, task_pri is some field I added in task_struct:

```
static inline void release_pri(struct task_struct *task)
{
        rbuffer_free(&(task->task_pri));
```

I have already include the header file "linux/sched.h". Can anyone explain me this?

There is another thing also confused me. I read the source code of "linux/kernel/exit.c". It doesn't include the header "linux/sched.h", so how can it use task_struct with no error?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30431

Comment: Thanks, but I think it's a different problem. My problem is the compiler can't find the definition of task_struct. I think my rewrite of ached.h has nothing to do with this.

Comment: It's not entirely clear how you are including sched.h. Is it within the header file that defines release_pri or is it in the C file that also includes the header containing release_pri? In any case, one way to debug is to pass "-E" to gcc to get the preprocessor output for the C file that is using release_pri. That will show you exactly where/if task_struct is appearing.

Comment: I include the header file in the header containing release_pri. I will try to check it by using -E.